# Python Socket - [Errno 35] Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, sockets

I am having issues with the sender function not receiving the data from the receiver function. When the sender sends the data, the receiver receives the data just fine. The receiver then sends an acknowledgement to the sender to show that it received the data just fine. However, the sending function does not recieve data from the receiver at all.

Here is the receiver function of sending the acknowledgment.

```
serversocket.sendto(str.encode(sequence), server_address)
```

I have no try Exception in the receiver, it doesn't throw an exception.
Here is the sender side of things:

```
        time_sent = time.time()
        ack_recv = None
        try:
            curr_time = time.time()
            time_received = curr_time - time_sent
            while(time_received < timeout_timer):
                #clientsocket.setblocking(False)
                clientsocket.setblocking(0)
                try:
                    ack_recv = clientsocket.recv(1024)
                    print("rdt_send: ack_num received: ", ack_recv.decode('utf-8'))
                    if ack_recv != None or ack_recv != b'0':
                        break
                except socket.error as err:
                    print(err)
                    #ass
                curr_time = time.time()
                time_received = curr_time - time_sent   
        except Exception as err:
            print(err)
```

In the try exception part of the sender side of things, it never prints out

```
print("rdt_send: ack_num received: ", ack_recv.decode('utf-8'))
```

It always goes to the exception.

The timeout_timer is set to 5.
Any thoughts on how to approach this?
In case it's needed, here is how I initialized the clientsocket (sender)

```
clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
```

Here is how I initialized the serversocket (reciever)

```
serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
server_address = ('localhost', port)
serversocket.bind(server_address)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's due to your non-blocking socket.  If the data isn't immediately available an error is raised.  Try again later or use `select` before your `recv` to ensure the socket is ready to receive, or don't use a non-blocking socket.